# BlackBerry10 Cascades: How to convert QObject to QVariant?

Tags: qt, blackberry, qobject, qvariant

I have a list of QObjects* and want to add them to my DataModel. But the datamodel needs a QVariant instead of QObject.

Is is possible to convert QObjects to QVariant?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because it is not a type supported by `QVariant::Type` it falls back to `QMetaType::Type` support.  You must use `QVariant::setValue(..)` or `QVariant::fromValue(..)` to [set](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvariant.html#setValue) it as the `QVariant` constructors don't have an overload for `QObject*`.